# Powershell Extracting Zip

Tags: powershell

When I run this command in a normal PowerShell window it works fine:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("c:/program/compressed.zip","c:/program")
```

However when I run it as:

```
powershell Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("c:/program/compressed.zip","c:/program")
```

or

```
cmd /c powershell Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("c:/program/compressed.zip","c:/program")
```

I get this error:

```
At line:1 char:119
+ ... System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory(c:/program/compressed.z ...
                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:119
+ ... System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory(c:/program/compressed.z ...
                                                                 ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:119
+ ... Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory(c:/program/compressed.zip,c:/progr ...
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'compressed.zip' in expression or statement.
```

How can I make it work when adding PowerShell in front?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: while windows is SUPPOSED to be able to use either "\" or "/" for a path delimiter ... have you tried using the OFFICIAL path delimiter? the "\" is the one that you really otta use ...

Answer (score 0):

Command Prompt (batch) processes the command and arguments first, so be careful with anything that could be interpreted as cmd symbols (double-quotes in your case), since cmd will remove them.

When running powershell commands, I prefer quoting the actual powershell part:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('c:/program/compressed.zip','c:/program')"
```